# Deleting rows from parent table with Foreign Key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete, referential-integrity

I have a Parent Table with Foreign Key and a Child Table with Primary Key. I want to delete only those rows of Parent Table which have no corresponding rows in Child table. I want to implement this in SQL Stored Procedure.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would just use `not exists`:

```
delete parent
    where not exists (select 1
                      from child
                      where child.parentid = parent.id
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `joins` (i.e. `left join`)

```
delete p from parent p
left join child c on c.parentid  = p.parentid 
where c.parentid  is null;
```